# When is a distribution normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, math-history

I see a lot of tutorial videos and papers that teach you how to use the normal distribution to find probabilities or that explain what the terms 'variance' and 'mean' mean, but I can't find one that gives me an explanation on why the function should even be a normal distribution.... I would like to know a real life example and a proof that a distribution function **of one variable**, say $x$, is actually normal without involving more than one dimension (like the darts example, where they use rotational symmetry).

Comment: One reason we use normal distributions so often is the central limit theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem.

Comment: Because of central limit theorem, normal distribution id so important.

Comment: The normal distribution is usually a good model, in particular if the random variable is the sum of many independent small components. In many situations (for example the error of a physical measurement) this is the case.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that several things that way say are "well modeled by" a normal distribution are not in actuality normally distributed.  The height of an adult male is an example, usually saying that it is well approximated by a normal distribution with mean $5'9''$ and standard deviation $3''$ (*or more accurate numbers depending on who you talk to*)., but this is absurd of course to think that it actually follows the normal distribution exactly since that would imply there is a **positive probability** of having a *negative height!*

Comment: @JMoravitz: The normal distribution is often a reasonable model even when negative values are impossible. If the mean is more than about four standard deviations above 0, there is no harm. Then a normal model truncated to avoid negative values would be indistinguishable from the untruncated model for all practical purposes. // Procedures using Student's t distribution often work well for data that are only 'roughly normal', but a responsible statistician will always check for serious departure from normal before using t methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of things that are not normally distributed... money in the economy, the brightness of stars, the magnitudes of earthquakes.

But, if you sum (or average) enough non-normally distributed random variables together, they the sum (or average) will increasingly resemble a normal distribution.  This is proved in the Central Limit Theorem.

Now there are plenty of processes that are approximately normally distributed -- grades in a class, the heights of the students, etc.
But if the height truly followed a normal distribution there would be a non-zero probability of having a student with a negative height.

Comment: And the grades can't follow it either, for similar reasons (they have both a maximum and a minimum possible value).

Comment: Indeed, but I thought that the heights example was more absurd.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder what makes one proposition "more absurd" than another, assuming that both propositions are, in fact, absurd.  I guess I usually think of absurdity in this sense as a Boolean property.

Comment: @GabrielBurns Do r.v. with bounds follow some other convergence?

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff not sure off the top of my head (I'm not really an expert on statistics) however, they certainly don't converge to a normal distribution, since it has a positive value for all $x$ in $(\infty,-\infty)$.